# Creating hybrid EditorKit which can alternate between for example markdown and source-code

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane, htmleditorkit

Say I have an EditorKit for CSS styled Html ([SwingBox](https://github.com/radkovo/SwingBox)), and I have an EditorKit for source code ([SyntaxKit](https://github.com/Sciss/SyntaxPane)). Can I create a synthetic editor kit for a `JEditorPane` that combines these two, so that I can have interleaved HTML (which would come from a markdown parser) and source code (handled by the SyntaxKit)?

E.g., like shown below. Note that I do *not* want to render the source code via a markdown-to-HTML parser, but use the specific syntax kit with its own lexer.

---

And here we have some ***literal*** programming stuff. With images [image] etc.

---

```
object Foo {
  def bar = 1234
}
```